# Validate collection elements in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a `List<File>` where I would like to ensure that each `File` element is a directory, and if it is not, throw an exception.

In Java I would do:

```
List<File> possibleDirs;
...
for (File possibleDir : possibleDirs) {
    if (!possibleDir.isDirectory()) throw new Exception();
    ...
}
```

but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this in groovy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is a better way to do this in groovy

What you have there is fine.  You could use some Groovy-isms like using a Closure for iterating:

```
possibleDirs.each { file ->
    if(!file.isDirectory()) {
        // throw exception...
    }
}
```

Or...

```
def allAreDirs = possibleDirs.every { file ->
    file.isDirectory()
}
if(!allAreDirs) {
    // throw exception...
}
```

I don't think either of those is really any better than what you have.  An argument against the `every` approach is that it has to visit every file where the previous approach and the approach you described bail out as soon as you know there is a problem.

**EDIT:**

I suppose you could also do something like:

```
if(possibleDirs.find { !it.isDirectory() }) {
    // throw exception...
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be some way to map the test to each element, rather than iterating

Comment: What is it that you are wanting to accomplish that your `for` loop doesn't satisfy?

Comment: a more functional approach rather than an iterative approach. As well as seeing if there would be a groovy idiom that "should" be used